# Google Analytics 4: How to find referring pages

Tags: google-analytics

In Google Analytics 4  is there a way to find internal referring pages.  I have a Not Found page and I see there are way too many hits on the page,  I would like to identify where they are coming from.

Existing information on Google is outdated it refers to "User Flow" or the "Audience" menu,  however these no longer exist in the current Google Analytics.  There seems to be no way for me to click on the Not Found page and find the referring pages.

Comment: Are you double tagging your site with both GA4 and Universal Anaytics?   Doing so is recommended until GA4 is more mature.  With dual tagging you could check UA for referrers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to Stephen for the GA4 Universal Analytics suggestion.  This works, but has the drawback that it requires the extra tagging which is in fact slow in terms of javascript execution.

I was able to find in the google Search Console tool,  by clicking on the "Coverage" link and clicking on the "Excluded" tab,  we can actually see many pages which generate the 404 error.  This is extremely useful and was sufficient for my case,  and requires no additional installs.